# reference variable used in ternary conditional? (ex: var?this:null)

Tags: groovy, conditional-statements, ternary

Is there a way to reference the first part of a `?:` statement in groovy?

For example, is there any way to shorten

```
def time = map.get('time') ? map.get('time').get('milliseconds') : null
```

to something like

```
def time = map.get('time') ? it.get('milliseconds') : null
```

, where "it" references the first part of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use the [safe navigation operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_safe_navigation_operator):

```
def time = map.get('time')?.get('milliseconds')
```

If `map.get('time')` returns a null reference, the result of the overall expression will be null, and `get('milliseconds')` won't be called.

Comment: @serg06, it could be `map.time?.milliseconds`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the safe navigation operator
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_safe_navigation_operator

so you can do this :

```
def time = map?.get('time')?.get('milliseconds')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [safe navigation operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator):

```
def time = map.get('time')?.get('milliseconds')
```

It ensures that `.get('milliseconds')` is not called if the result of `map.get('time')` is `null`. The overall result of the expression in this case would also be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply:

```
map.time?.milliseconds
```